# How to filter VCF file with a list CHR or contig IDs?

Tags: vcf-variant-call-format, vcftools

I need to subset/filter a SNP vcf file by a long list of non-sequential contig IDs, which appear in the CHR column. My VCF file contains 13,971 contigs currently, and I want to retain a specific set of 7,748 contigs and everything associated with those contigs (all variants and genotype information etc.).

My contig list looks like:

dDocent_Contig_1

dDocent_Contig_100

dDocent_Contig_10000 etc.

I am considering the following script:
`vcftools --vcf TotalRawSNPs.vcf --chr dDocent_Contig_1 --chr dDocent_Contig_100 (etc...) --recode --recode-INFO-all --out FinalRawSNPs`

where I list every contig ID individually with a --chr flag before. For this --chr flag, I cannot feed it a text file of contig IDs to keep, which would be ideal. If I list all contigs individually, it'll create a massive script in the command line.

I’ve seen options for filtering by a list of individuals, but not any clear option for filtering by CHR/contig IDs only. Is there a more efficient way to filter my vcf file by CHR/contig?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do similar - delete numerous specific contigs/Chrom from a VCF. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I was able to find assistance on another site. See this link for the coding and how it worked out for me: https://www.biostars.org/p/443653/#446904

I had found this workaround a little bit bulky. However, it worked great for my experience level at the time. Another piece of coding that you might be able to customize for your purposes is the remove.bad.hap.loci.sh script found here: https://github.com/jpuritz/dDocent/blob/master/scripts/remove.bad.hap.loci.sh